# How to compute the expected value of the number of domains of a given size?

Tags: probability, expected-value, geometric-probability

Given a regular lattice (i.e., a finite set of identical squares - or triangles, or hexagons - stacked next to each other as a large rectangle - or some other shape), each border between cells is randomly removed (with given probability), so now we have domains of different sizes.

***What is the expected number of domains of size 1, 2, 3 &c?***

**PS1**. E.g., the simplest non-trivial case is probably this: the lattice is 4 triangles forming a double triangle:

[image: 4 triangles]

Suppose each of $DE$, $EF$ and $DF$ is removed with probability $p$ (say, $p=\frac13$). 
What is the expected number of domains of size 1, 2, 3 and 4?
(each smaller triangle, e.g., $ADF$ has size 1).

This is solved trivially by brute force, so I am ***NOT*** interested in solving it. I am only bringing is as an ***illustration***.

Here is the answer ($r$ is the number of removed borders, $d$ is the domain size):

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
   & r=0 & r=1 & r=2 & r=3 & \mathbb{E} \\\hline
P(r) & (1-p)^3 & 3(1-p)^2p & 3(1-p)p^2 & p^3 &  \\\hline
d=1 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 2(1-p)^2(2+p) \\\hline
d=2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 3(1-p)^2p \\\hline
d=3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 3(1-p)p^2 \\\hline
d=4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & p^3 \\\hline
\end{array}
$$

Another simple example is a $2\times2$ square where there are **4** possible internal borders to remove:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
   & r=0 & r=1 & r=2(1) & r=2(2) & r=3 & r=4 & \mathbb{E} \\\hline
P(r) & (1-p)^4 & 4(1-p)^3p & 3(1-p)^2p^2 & 3(1-p)^2p^2 & 4(1-p)p^3 & p^4 \\\hline
d=1 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & (1-p)^2(4-p^2) \\\hline
d=2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2(1-p)^2p(2+p) \\\hline
d=3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3(1-p)^2p^2 \\\hline
d=4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & p^3(4-3p) \\\hline
\end{array}
$$

**PS2**. I am interested in **methodology** rather than in a specific solution for any particular limited case.

Comment: In your example, brute-force gives the expected number of parts with area $1$ is $\frac{62}{27}$, area $2$ is $\frac{12}{27}$, area $3$ is  $\frac{6}{27}$, and area $4$ is $\frac1{27}$.  I do not see an obvious way to generalise this

Comment: @Henry I know, but this method does _not_ generalize ;-(

Comment: Why do you think that this problem has a solution that can be explained on these pages?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: I have my reasons ;-) I am pretty sure there is a clever trick like representing my variable as a sum of (many) simpler variables that would allow for easy computation of the expectation.